# Collada dae Model is not displayed Angular 16

Tags: angular, collada, 3d-model

Could you help find out why some dae models are not displayed? My code:

```
    private createScene() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var loader = new ColladaLoader();
         loader.load('assets/model.dae', (collada: any) => {
             let m=collada.scene;
             console.log(m);
             this.scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 ) );
             this.scene.add(m);
             this.render();
           }, undefined, function ( error ) {
                console.error( error );
     
         });
    }
```

I tried several 3D model viewers for Dae Collada. It works in some of them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDCiL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUi3d.png)